# Laravel RouteNotFoundException

Tags: laravel, routes

I am learning Laravel and getting the route error when adding the delete route

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [deletestyle/] not defined. (View: G:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\resources\views\styles\style.blade.php)

Route

```
Route::delete('/deletestyle/{id}', 'StyleController@destroy');
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id){
        try{
            $style = Style::findorFail($id);
            
            if($style->delete()){
                return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Style deleted successfully']);
            }
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

View

```
<a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="{{ route('deletestyle/').$style->id }}">Delete</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

route should be like this :

```
Route::get('/deletestyle/{id}', 'StyleController@destroy')->name('delete.style');
```

and view should be like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="{{ route('delete.style',$style->id) }}">Delete</a></div>
```

if you want delete as method type you have to use form  with method spoofing using `@method('delete')`

for more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: my pleasure happy coding